# Dynamically created button not firing Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating dynamic controls, in that one control is a button.
I used the following code to add the button control.

```
Button btnContinue = new Button();
btnContinue.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
btnContinue.ID = "btnContinue";
btnContinue.Text = "Continue";
btnContinue.CausesValidation = false;
btnContinue.Click += new EventHandler(btnContinue_Click);                
lineAdd.Controls.Add(btnContinue);
```

And the button click event as below.

```
protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

This event is not firing. Any idea why this is not firing the event. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the code surrounding your button add code? where abouts in the page life cycle are you adding it?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i am creating the button in the page load  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) ........................................Adding the other controls and the button .....................................................}
            {

Comment: Look at BritishDevelopers answer, it looks like it's right. Creating your button in the `Page_Load` Will not create the button and link up events correctly. Make sure you put your code into the  `Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)` method, if it doesn't exist in your page, create it. ( You should be able to use override )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your are creating that button early enough in the page lifecycle. Look to get it created OnInit of the Page.

This is because the event handling events happen after Page Init. Of course the button has to have been created before the events can detected on it. The joy of web forms...

Answer (score 1):

You MUST initialize dynamically created controls inside the OnInit() method (see [MS kb post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794)), or the page will not consider it.
Note that the control must be created also during the postback caused by the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the UseSubmitBehavior property to True.